# Wake up application on tapping Push Notifications in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to integrate Push notifications to the application. 
The behaviour i am trying to implement is waking up the app from background and resuming to previous state. 
But the control always come to `protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)` 
initially and then to OnResume upon tapping the notification message instead of coming 
to `protected async override void OnResume().` 
Because of this the app is always relaunching instead of waking up.

How can i just wake the app instead of relaunching when tapped on notification.?

Here is how the notification is created.

```
private void CreateNotification(string title, string desc, string type)
        {           
            Random random = new Random();
            int id = random.Next(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
            const int pendingIntentId = id;
            const int notificationId = id;

            var startupIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));         
            var stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);

            stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)));
            stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(startupIntent);

            var pendingIntent =         
                stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(pendingIntentId, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            var builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .SetContentTitle(title)
                .SetContentText(desc)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.appicon);

            var notification = builder.Build();
            notification.Flags = NotificationFlags.AutoCancel;

            var notificationManager =
                GetSystemService(NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
        }
```

Other scenarios like when the app is not running and in foreground are working as expected.